# AWS STSの各リージョンエンドポイントを有効/無効を選択できる理由

Tags: aws, aws-iam

STSの各リージョンエンドポイントは有効/無効にできますが何故でしょうか？
無闇に有効すると、どのようなセキュリティ脅威がありますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: "詳細はこちら" のリンク先は確認しましたか？

Answer (score 0):

> 何故でしょうか？

それはサービスの設計思想の話なのでAWSに直接聞いてください。

使用しないリージョンを無効化しておくことによって、使用しないリージョンに対する不必要なアクセスが制限できるというメリットがあります。
ただ、個人的にはそこで縛らなくてもIAMポリシーできちんと縛れば多くの場合十分だと思っています。